# INSERT полей из List в базу данных с помощью Spring Data JPA и @Entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Всем привет!)

1.У меня есть ***List valuteCurs*** `valuteCurs.add(new ValuteCurs(NumCode, CharCode, Nominal, Name, Value))`

2. Есть **сущность**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "base_currency")
public class ValuteCursEntity extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name = "num_code")
    private int num_code;

    @Column (name = "char_code")
    private String char_code;

    @Column(name = "nominal")
    private int nominal;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;
```

3. Есть ***репозиторий***

```
@Repository
public interface ValuteCursRepository extends JpaRepository<ValuteCursEntity, Long> {
}
```

4. От меня требуется добавить данные поля объекта в БД. Я еще стажер Java но задача есть задача)) Кто может помочь советом, сижу который час уже.
5. Пробовал такой метод ***getValuteCursEntity()*** в классе ***XmlParser***

```
 ValuteCursEntity valuteCursEntity = new ValuteCursEntity();
        for (ValuteCurs vc : valuteCurs){
            valuteCursEntity.setNum_code(vc.getNumCode());
            valuteCursEntity.setValue(vc.getValue());
            valuteCursEntity.setNominal(vc.getNominal());
            valuteCursEntity.setName(vc.getName());
            valuteCursEntity.setChar_code(vc.getCharCode());
        }
        return valuteCursEntity;
```

И дальше в контроллере сохранить эту сущность в репозиторий.

```
 @GetMapping
    public List<ValuteCursEntity> getValuteCurs () throws Exception {
        valuteCursRepository.save(xmlParser.getValuteCursEntity());
        return valuteCursRepository.findAll();
    }
```

***НО СОХРАНЯЕТСЯ В БД ТОЛЬКО ПОСЛЕДНИЙ ОБЪЕКТ ИЗ List***(пробовал два раза)
Не могу это обойти, подскажите как быть!)
Спасибо)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Парс XML:***

```
public class XmlParser {

    public ValuteCursEntity getValuteCursEntity() throws Exception {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new URL("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp").openStream());


        List<ValuteCurs> valuteCurs = new ArrayList<>();
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element elem = (Element) node;

                Integer NumCode = Integer.parseInt(elem.getElementsByTagName("NumCode")
                        .item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

                String CharCode = elem.getElementsByTagName("CharCode").item(0)
                        .getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();

                Integer Nominal = Integer.parseInt(elem.getElementsByTagName("Nominal")
                        .item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

                String Name = elem.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0)
                        .getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();

                String Value = elem.getElementsByTagName("Value").item(0)
                        .getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();

                valuteCurs.add(new ValuteCurs(NumCode, CharCode, Nominal, Name, Value));
            }
        }
```

***И класс ***

```
@Data
public class ValuteCurs {

    private int numCode;
    private String charCode;
    private int nominal;
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public ValuteCurs(int numCode, String charCode, int nominal, String name, String value) {

        this.numCode = numCode;
        this.charCode = charCode;
        this.nominal = nominal;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, как вы парсите xml в объект

Comment: Не используйте транслит в нейминге сущностей - такие классы никогда не пройдут ревью. Переименуйте сущности на английские слова - ValuteCursEntity должно стать CurrencyRateEntity (или просто Currency, а курс отдельно хранить - в сущности CurrencyRate). Репозиторий тоже переименовать не помешало бы

Comment: Добавил парс (нагуглил более менее понятный для себя способ), а на счет нейминга - спасибо!, я просто наименования давал как в XML.

Comment: по поводу имен - см. в ответе

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в проект [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) и используйте его для маппинга из ValuteCurs в ValuteCursEntity.

Либо создайте еще одну коллекцию, типизированную ValuteCursEntity и добавляйте в нее сразу вместо создания объекта ValuteCurs.

Ваш класс должен принять такой вид после правок:

```
public class XmlParser {

    public Collection<ValuteCursEntity> getValuteCursEntity() throws Exception {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new URL("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp").openStream());


        List<ValuteCursEntity> currencies = new ArrayList<>();
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element elem = (Element) node;

                Integer NumCode = Integer.parseInt(elem.getElementsByTagName("NumCode")
                        .item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

                String CharCode = elem.getElementsByTagName("CharCode").item(0)
                        .getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();

                Integer Nominal = Integer.parseInt(elem.getElementsByTagName("Nominal")
                        .item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

                String Name = elem.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0)
                        .getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();

                String Value = elem.getElementsByTagName("Value").item(0)
                        .getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();

                currencies.add(new ValuteCursEntity(NumCode, CharCode, Nominal, Name, Value));
            }
        }
        return currencies;
    }
}
```

Далее в репозитории вам необходимо сохранять полученную коллецию методом saveAll().

Не используйте в именах переменных подчеркивания - в java принят стиль наименования CamelCase. 
Ознакомиться с соглашениями о наименованиях можно [здесь](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Еще момент - у вас логика сохранения прописана в классе контроллера и идет напрямую обращение к нему. Вынесите в отдельный класс эту логику и его вызывайте в контроллере.

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста поподробнее, про новую коллекцию типизированную ValuteCursEntity - не доходит до меня, за все остальное спасибо!, вроде понятно

Comment: Вам же в методе getValuteCursEntity необходимо получить коллекцию сущностей ValuteCursEntity, а не сущностей ValuteCurs, чтобы потом сохранить.

Comment: В оригинальном коде создается коллекция, типизированная ValuteCurs и чтобы получить искомую коллекцию необходимо вновь по уже созданному List<ValuteCurs> пройтись, для каждого элемента создать новый ValuteCursEntity и положить его в какую-то коллекцию, чтобы потом ее из метода вернуть.

Comment: Ну и чтобы не делать одно и то же два раза - проще создавать сразу искомую сущность ValuteCursEntity (данных для этого хватает) и помещать ее в результат работы метода